# How to import a graph from Cytoscape to R?

Tags: r, graph-theory, cytoscape

I generated a network model in cytoscape and wanted to do some analysis on it using R. However, I'm unsure how I can import my graph from cytoscape into an analyzable form in R. I've tried reading it into R as a SIF file and XGGML file, but none have worked so far. All the functions I have found have resulted in either errors, or are out of date.

Does anyone know how I could read in a cytoscape graph into R?

Thanks so much!

Comment: [This](https://www.bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/vignettes/RCy3/inst/doc/Cytoscape-and-iGraph.html) should answer your question

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the G5W's comments, [RCy3](https://bioconductor.org/packages/release/bioc/html/RCy3.html) is the solution. You can import, modify, and export graph in Cytoscape through R this way. Similar code block as follows should should work:

```
require(RCy3)
cytoscapePing()
cytoscapeVersionInfo()
openSession("Your cytoscape session file")#
Sys.sleep(1)
setCurrentView("The cytoscape view you are working on")
nodetab=getTableColumns(table="node")
```

1. You need to have Cytoscape opened when running this block and adding `Sys.sleep(1)` might solve some of your errors.
2. You can change to `table="edge"` to load the edge table.